# Popover window in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, popover

Is there a way to have a popover window that goes beyond the boundary of the main window? Doesn't have to be a child window. But would be great if it's attached to the main window. I know there's modal window option, but that's not exactly the look I'm aiming for.

Example of popover window:

[image: Example of popover window]

Any tricks to achieve something like this in Electron? 
Thanks!

(I'm building this in React, if that's good to note)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gitscout](https://gitscout.com/)'s guys discussed this in a San-Francisco based (and then Paris based) Electron Meetup.
You can find the video [here](https://youtu.be/EruDxnLK_bg?t=19m4s), the deck [here](https://speakerdeck.com/gitscout/gitscout-at-electron-techtalks-sf) and the code [there](https://github.com/gitscout/sf-electron-tech-talks).

The bottom line of their talk is that it's possible: they create a dedicated `BrowserWindow` for the popover on top of the main one and synchronize the 2. However, it requires a lot of work to have a perfect user experience.